# Reset classpath

Tags: java, linux

I ran `export CLASSPATH=/home/deltrem/jscheme/jscheme.jar`, but now kawa, which was working, doesn't work any longer. Is there a way to revert the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

set CLASSPATH=

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

Comment: So you want it for windows or for linux?

Comment: I've just noticed the win32 in the url. I want it for linux.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using it from terminal you can close that terminal window and open a new one.
or

```
export CLASSPATH=
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export CLASSPATH=
```

Yes, it work in my environment (linux ubuntu 18.04).